# Dynamic Allocation of Array doesn't work for ArrayAdapter while assigning it for Spinner in Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, dialog

I am really facing a problem here to create a Spinner widget in Android. The goal is to populate a Spinner with data that i will dynamically retrieve from a source.
Now I am able to create a spinner with a data source that is implicitly declared in the program. But when ever i am trying to fetch the data from a dynamically created array, the apps throws a Force Close.
I will paste some demo examples to explain my problem here!

```
String[] SSID = new String[15];
String[] Data = {"Captain","America","Hulk","Ironman","Thor"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    addDevDialogue = new Dialog(this);
    addDevDialogue.setContentView(R.layout.popup);

    concat();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialogue();

        }
    });


}


public void concat()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        SSID[i]=Data[i];

    }

}

public void dialogue()
{
    addDevDialogue.setTitle("Movies List");
    addDevDialogue.setCancelable(true);
    addDevDialogue.show();

    spinList2 = (Spinner)addDevDialogue.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, SSID);
    spinList2.setAdapter(listAdapter2);



}
```

The above code throws an error when ever I try to open the dialogue box.
I have tried this same sample with a pre-defined data source in place of "SSID" which yields a error free output!

I cannot understand why 'SSID[]' array doesnt work when I define it to the ArrayAdapter.
Any Insight will help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are call calling show() before populating adapter so call

```
addDevDialogue.show();
```

after

```
spinList2.setAdapter(listAdapter2);
```

**UPDATE :**

Once change size of SSID

```
String[] SSID = new String[Data.length];
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Well I have tried what you mentioned, but still it throws an error!

I have tried this with "Data[]" instead of "SSID"...it seems to work though!

I think the prob is with the SSID array
Can u please help!

Comment: @SwarnanEel once create SSID array with size of Data array as above.

Comment: Well I tried it and it still throws an error!

Shall i post the error Log?

Comment: @SwarnanEel why you are copying Data array to SSID, you can use directly Data at the time of creating adapter.

Comment: Yes good question. Actually this is just a demo program. The actual implementation is on another program which is too lengthy. :)
Solving this problem here in this program will help me on that!
Anyway, it seems that there is a " Fatal Exception: main java.lang.NullPointerException " on the array adapter.
Can you please see to it.
This problem is driving me nuts!
much thanks for giving me your time! :)

Comment: @SwarnanEel Actually your SSID size is 15 but you are storing only 5 in that and remaining contains null so at the time of setting adapter it is trying to set null so it is throwing NullPointerException.

Comment: WOW....It worked!
Thanks a ton brother! :)
It really helped !

But I have a question, is there anyway to make the size of the SSID[] adjustable dynamically to the size of the Data[]?

Comment: @SwarnanEel At the time of creating SSID array give size of Data, and dont forget to accept this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brother. You are a lifesaver! :)
Wish I could give 10 acceptance! :)
thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Your string array `String[] Data = {"Captain","America","Hulk","Ironman","Thor"};` is declared with 5 elements (index 0-4)

In your loop you loop 6 times

```
public void concat()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        SSID[i]=Data[i];    
    }    
}
```

Which probably causes an Index out of bounds exception. Change your loop to this

```
public void concat()
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        SSID[i]=Data[i];

    }
}
```

Comment: No, I have 5 data in the array and the loop runs 5 times only.

It runs from 0 to 4 since i hv given i<5 and not i<=5.

Comment: No it does not. Your loop loops 6 times. @Swarna nEel

Answer (score 0):

@swarna: You are allocating a fixed array of 15 elements, then populating only 5 elements. The array adapter is probably getting tripped with the other 10 elements which have not been initialized. Suggest you make your SSID array to have only 5 elements OR if this is a dynamically determined value, you could keep ArrayList and keep adding to it. Then, when setting up the adapter do this:

```
    YourObjList.add("one")
    YourObjList.add("two")
    YourObjList.add("three")

    String[] SSID = YourObjList.toArray(new YourObjList[YourObjList.size()]);

    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, SSID);
    spinList2.setAdapter(listAdapter2);
```

This will allow variable list sizes.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! 
I have already fixed the problem.
Yes it was tripping for the last 10 null values on the SSID[] array!